# What is the takeaway of cofibrant generation?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

I have recently begun reading about model categories. In particular, I have been using Balchin's *A Handbook of Model Categories* as a reference, and the following quote has been quite perplexing.

> A cofibrantly generated model category has a small set of cofibrations (resp.,
> acyclic cofibrations) that generate all other cofibrations (resp., acyclic cofibrations).
> Many arguments are much easier to check under this assumption as conditions can
> be checked on the generating sets.

My question is as follows: what are some motivating examples of the aforementioned arguments that might be easier to check on generating sets? For instance, the classical model structure on simplicial sets can be realized as a cofibrantly generated model category, with generating cofibrations being the boundary inclusions and generating acyclic cofibrations being the horn inclusions. Are there arguments that are easier to check on these generating sets than it might otherwise be without invoking the cofibrantly generated model structure?

Essentially, I am in search of statements of the form "It suffices to show _____ for a generating cofibration." Some such examples can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6873.pdf) in Propositions 1.4 and 5.2. However, I happened upon this paper after searching a rather wide range of literature, and could not help but wonder if there are more clear examples that come to mind.

Comment: There are lots of such proofs, but they may not use such language. Actually most of them do not rely on the existence of a _set_ of generating cofibrations – it usually is enough to have some class of generating cofibrations that are explicit enough to work with. In a few crucial proofs you do need to know that there is a _set_ of generating cofibrations – but curiously these proofs usually do not require explicit descriptions of the generating cofibrations, just the fact that there are not too many of them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Do you have some motivating examples of such proofs? Since posting the comment, I have found several proofs here and there that do indeed make use of the quote from Balchin that I mentioned, but none seem to be incredibly outstanding to me in a way that renders the quote to be more than just a comment in passing as opposed to a slogan for an entire chapter on cofibrant generation.

Comment: Well, how about the fact that diagrams in combinatorial model categories comprise themselves combinatorial model categories?

Comment: The small object argument is probably the most prominent one that requires a _set_ of morphisms, and will simply not work with a proper class.  As for other examples, consider the proof that the model structure on simplicial sets is cartesian: the pushout product of boundary inclusions and/or horn inclusions can be easily shown to be a cofibration respectively acyclic cofibration, unlike the general case.

Comment: It's generally easier to check if a map is a fibration if the model structure is cofibrantly generated, as you just have to check the lifting property against the generating trivial cofibrations vs all the trivial cofibrations.